# Meteor href in email

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, meteor

I'm trying to send an email with an href in its body.

```
const link= document.createElement("a");
link.href = window.location.href;

emailDetails.body = "Here is an href: \r\n" + link;

Meteor.call("sendEmail", emailDetails.to, email, emailDetails.subject, emailDetails.body);
```

Where my Email method is

```
sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, html) {
check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

this.unblock();

Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  html: html
});
```

But I'm having no luck. Source of the actual email message does show the anchor tag, but no href inside it.

I've also tried putting the html in a template and then compiling the template using

```
SRR.compileTemplate
```

and passing that result as my email body. But that doesn't work either. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Gmail wouldn't render the anchor tag, but Outlook does. So it's an issue with how the email client treats embedded html.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's possible, just use plain tags; instead of `document.createElement("a")`.

```
smtp = {
    username: "server@gentlenode.com", 
    password: "3eeP1gtizk5eziohfervU",  
    server: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587
  };

  process.env.MAIL_URL =
    "smtp://" +
    encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) +
    ":" +
    encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) +
    "@" +
    encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) +
    ":" +
    smtp.port;

  Email.send({
    to: "duckduck@quack.com",
    from: "mew2@gmail.com",
    subject: "hello",
    html: `<p><strong>This will render as bold text</strong>, but this will not.</p> Also, You can direct users to <a href="duckduckgo.com">duckduckgo</a>`
  });
```

https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-the-email-package

Comment: Plain tags didn't work for me at one instance. I can try it exactly how you did it later on and see what's different though